# How to Store Sever Broadcast Message in Client Side

Tags: c#, angular, signalr

I am working on a Project in which I am broadcasting a message from server and displaying it in Client Side.

I wanted to store the same server received message in client side. I just wanted to ask how can I store the same.

API is created using C# and Front End is angular
Concept for broadcasting is signalR

Comment: How would you lke to store it?  File, Database, Upload to cloud?   QUestion has too many answers.

Comment: May you take `localStorage` into account. This offers the possibility store whatever you want on the client.

Comment: @Neil Sorry I did not mentioned earlier Database storage I want to perform

Comment: @Daniel Can you please tell how can I do the same

Comment: https://localforage.github.io/localForage/

Comment: @guzmanoj Thanks for the help 
But can you tell any method to store in Database. 
Or how can I use local forage for storing the data in data base

Comment: Maybe review this, https://www.sitepoint.com/client-side-storage-options-comparison/ , but as it says your browser is sandboxed so you are going to have limited options for a database.